# Dygraphs: is it possible to mix series with and without error bars?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I've got some graphs where I'm using error bars to display a fan chart. This works well. I also want to display individual series without error bars as an overlay. I've got lots of these individual series, which I display one at a time using the visibility option, but the problem is that I have to construct the data in the error bar format: ie, 3 values, all identical, for each time step. Is there any way of avoiding this?

The data ends up looking like this (for t=1)

```
[1, [5, 50, 95], [10, 50, 90], [25, 50, 75]... [27, 27, 27], [30, 30, 30], [61, 61, 61]]
```

where the ones before the ellipsis are the fan chart data, and the ones after are the individual series.

Edit:
Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lpryor/w9y1z3hq/1/) of a simplified version (it has only one individual series, which is always visible)

Comment: Would be great to show some of the code.

Comment: Did you find any solution yet? Also looking forward to mix errorbar series with normal lines/points.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the same value three times to plot an individual series is reasonable. You could also pass `null` as the low and high value for the individual series, as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w9y1z3hq/2/):

```
var barValues = [
    [1, [34, 34, 34],
        [30, 35, 40],
        [25, 35, 45],
        [20, 35, 50],
        [null, 37, null]  // <-- individual series
    ],
    ...
    ];
```

The `customBars` option affects how the data is parsed, and this sort of behavior can't be set per-series. So there's no better way without writing your own DataLoader, which would be more hassle than adding `null`s or repeating the value.

If the `null`s bother you, you could always factor out a function:

```
function single(x) { return [null, x, null]; }
var barValues = [
    [1, [34, 34, 34],
        [30, 35, 40],
        [25, 35, 45],
        [20, 35, 50],
        single(37)
    ],
    ...
    ];
```